# <td> Spacing not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-tables

Basically, I want to space my `td`s apart from each other horizontally. In Firefox, it works fine by setting a margin, but the margin doesn't work in chrome. So I tried the following and applied it to the table

```
border-spacing: 40px;
border-collapse: separate;
```

Moreover, that solution worked in chrome, but NOT Firefox; even though guides suggested that I need the `border-collapse:` separate to have it work in firefox.

Without any further detail, here's the code for the table styling (the one that works in Firefox):

```
#tstyle3 {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0px;
    width: 750px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

#tstyle3 tr {
    height: 270px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 950px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#tstyle3 td {
    border-top: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-collapse: separate;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    height: 220px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #b5b6b6;
}
```

And the situation recreated in jsfiddle (which shows how it appears in Firefox)

http://jsfiddle.net/JjZNb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about you try something more sexy like

```
float:left; display:block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JjZNb/1/

Comment: floats are automatically converted to block

Comment: You seem to have found the solution. Thanks my friend!

Comment: Make sure to add "overflow:hidden" to your "#table" so height of container is calculated for next DOM elements.

Comment: Hey there,Note that I didn't use table in example. Tables are hard to modify and to read in general. Please look at my jsfiddle example and see how it makes the code cleaner. Of course some people will disagree but that's a personal advice, use floating divs instead of tables.

Comment: @mika - On all browsers. It's in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-float

Comment: @Rob and we all know how browsers implements specs :-) I think it will cause issues in IE if Block is missing.

Comment: @mika - If it's not converted to block, then it can only be inline which can't be moved from its position. Look in any of the developer tools of any browser and you'll see it though, I agree, you can never trust IE to do anything right.

Answer (score 0):

You can add spacing by specifying a border size, or padding for your td elements.

```
td{border:8px solid #fff;}
```

or for padding

```
td{padding:0 10px;}
```

or when border styles are already defined,

```
td{border-width:2px;}
```

or for each side

```
td{border-width:0 2px 0 2px;}
/* top right bottom left*/
```

here is a jsFiddle that demonstrates the above http://jsfiddle.net/VjkP9/

Answer (score 0):

> Margin does not work for td elements.

That's not quite right.  Margin doesn't work for table cells (so elements with `display:table-cell`.  But the CSS above styles the `<td>` elements with `display: inline-block`, so they aren't table cells anymore and margin should be applying to them.